# What stops Word from inserting spaces after a word wrap?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

In Word 2007, I have a sentence like this:

> 1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

This is all plain text (not numbered). There are no hard linebreaks, it is all word wrapped. There are a couple of thousands lines like this from 1 to 2000+. Attempting to convert them to Numbering in Word messes up all the formatting (like it changes `5) blah blah` to `1. 5) blah blah`) so I am instead trying to push the spacing over to the right below the first line, so it looks like:

```
 1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
    nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

But when I'm typing in spaces at the start of those lines, nothing happens. If I turn on View Special Characters, I can see the spaces being inserted instead at the line above at the end of the line (thus nothing happening).

How can I space text over in Word after a word wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word wraps at the beginning of the word, after all the previous spaces, so you can't fool it. Instead, open the Bullets and Numbering dialog, and choose the `1)` numbering format.

If you really don't want to use Word's numbering, then use a hanging indent. This works by indenting the text, but unindenting the first line of the text.

Comment: Again, I tried that and it messes all the formatting up so that isn't a viable solution. I tried hanging indents, but they are a static number and each paragraph here sometimes starts at different positions.